# How to find out what version of Java EE specification websphere uses?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I'd like to know which version of Java EE specification is provided by my Websphere application server (traditional, not Liberty). Unfortunately I don't know where to find such information. WAS version is

```
WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.11 [BASE 8.5.5.11 cf111649.01] [IBMJAVA8 8.0.3.20 cf111647.02]
```

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html

Comment: I think you should post is as an anwer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly with IBM doc it should be version 6.

The complete list is here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked about WebSphere Application Server traditional base 8.5.5, the definitive answer is JEE6 as listed in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html).  WAS traditional v9 brings the spec level to EE7 as noted [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/covr_javaee7.html).  Liberty, as noted in [this KnowledgeCenter doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_javaee7.html), has supported JEE7 since version 8.5.5.6 .  The Oracle doc referenced above verifies that WAS Liberty is JEE7 certified from 8.5.5.6 and that WAS traditional is from v9.

Answer (score -1):

Your version is compliant with Java EE 7, and has been certified by Oracle. You can see that at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html which lists all Java EE certified servers.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. Here is jee 6 metioned for all 8.5.5 servers https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html. Maybe jee 7 is provided only for "liberty profile".

Comment: According to the link Java EE 7 is supported from 8.5.5.6. You can test whether or not it is supported by using the Java EE 7 samples against it, which can be found at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples.

Comment: You're reading the wrong section of your link.  The full Java EE 7 stack is only supported by WebSphere 9.0 and above; the reference to 8.5.5.6 on that page is for the Java EE 7 Web Profile, a subset of the full EE release, and even that is only implemented by the Liberty server, not the traditional server (which the original poster is using, per the version output).

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific about server's version.